# Office-addin Authentication, approval process

Tags: office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, appsource

I'm currently using Auth0 authentication in my add-in. Now, I want to allow users to use my add-in without authentication. 
**If I remove the authentication,do I have to send my add-in again for approval to Microsoft team?**

Answer (score -2):

It is recommended that after any changes are made in the add-in, it is resubmitted to validation to ensure it is compliant with current policies.